# Android Display Unicode Character from website to TextView

Tags: android, html, unicode, web, jsoup

I'm coding Android and processing request from address
"http://www.mytvnet.vn/module/ajax/ajax_get_schedule.php?channelId=100&dateSchedule=18%2F01%2F2014"

The result of the request is

```
"

06:00<\/strong> Ch\u00e0o bu\u1ed5i s\u00e1ng<\/p>

06:30<\/strong> Ng\u00e0y m\u1edbi<\/p>

06:50<\/strong> B\u1ea3n tin Th\u1ecb tr\u01b0\u1eddng<\/p>

07:00<\/strong> Vi\u1ec7t Nam m\u1ebfn y\u00eau : Kh\u00e1m ph\u00e1 Tr\u00e0ng An<\/p>

07:20<\/strong> Qu\u00e0 t\u1eb7ng cu\u1ed9c s\u1ed1ng<\/p>

07:30<\/strong> T\u00ecnh kh\u00fac v\u01b0\u1ee3t th\u1eddi gian<\/p>

08:00<\/strong> Y h\u1ecdc ph\u01b0\u01a1ng \u0110\u00f4ng : \u0110i\u1ec1u tr\u1ecb b\u1ec7nh \u0111au d\u00e2y th\u1ea7n kinh t\u1ecda<\/p>

08:30<\/strong> Kh\u00e1m ph\u00e1 : Xanh bi\u1ebfc r\u1eebng Tr\u00e0m<\/p>

08:50<\/strong> S\u1ed1ng kh\u1ecfe : Ph\u00f2ng ch\u1ed1ng b\u1ec7nh b\u00e9o ph\u00ec<\/p>

09:10<\/strong> Chuy\u1ec7n \u0111\u00e0n \u00f4ng : L\u1ea5y v\u1ee3 mu\u1ed9n<\/p>

09:30<\/strong> Vi\u1ec7t nam \u2013 \u0111\u1ea5t n\u01b0\u1edbc, con ng\u01b0\u1eddi : Th\u1ecb x\u00e3 b\u00ean s\u00f4ng B\u00e9<\/p>

10:00<\/strong> Phim truy\u1ec7n : H\u1ea1nh ph\u00fac mu\u1ed9n m\u00e0ng - t\u1eadp 31<\/p>

11:00<\/strong> V\u0103n ngh\u1ec7 thi\u1ebfu nhi : Ti\u1ebfng chim l\u00edu lo<\/p>

11:15<\/strong> Ti\u1ebfng n\u00f3i c\u1eed tri<\/p>

11:30<\/strong> Th\u1eddi s\u1ef1 VTV Ph\u00fa Y\u00ean<\/p>

11:45<\/strong> Th\u1ecb tr\u01b0\u1eddng cu\u1ed1i tu\u1ea7n<\/p>

11:50<\/strong> Phim truy\u1ec7n : M\u1eaft b\u01b0\u1edbm - t\u1eadp 28<\/p>

12:50<\/strong> K\u00fd \u1ee9c mi\u1ec1n T\u00e2y : D\u1eeba \u01a1i ta nh\u1edb!<\/p>

13:00<\/strong> Kh\u00e1m ph\u00e1 Vi\u1ec7t Nam : Ba su\u1ed1i c\u00e1 Th\u1ea7n<\/p>

13:10<\/strong> B\u1ebfp Vi\u1ec7t : V\u1ecbt n\u01b0\u1edbng l\u00e1 l\u1ed1t<\/p>

13:40<\/strong> Ph\u00f3ng s\u1ef1 : M\u1ed9t ch\u1ee7 tr\u01b0\u01a1ng h\u1ee3p l\u00f2ng d\u00e2n<\/p>

14:00<\/strong> \u00c2m nh\u1ea1c v\u00e0 B\u01b0\u1edbc nh\u1ea3y<\/p>

14:30<\/strong> Nh\u1eefng m\u1ea3nh gh\u00e9p cu\u1ed9c s\u1ed1ng : Nh\u1eefng th\u01b0\u01a1ng c\u1ea3ng trong l\u1ecbch s\u1eed Vi\u1ec7t Nam - ph\u1ea7n 8<\/p>

15:00<\/strong> Phim truy\u1ec7n : C\u00e1 r\u00f4, em y\u00eau em - t\u1eadp 13<\/p>

16:00<\/strong> V\u0103n ngh\u1ec7 thi\u1ebfu nhi : Gi\u1ea5c m\u01a1 c\u1ed5 t\u00edch<\/p>

16:25<\/strong> Qu\u00e0 t\u1eb7ng cu\u1ed9c s\u1ed1ng<\/p>

16:30<\/strong> Phim t\u00e0i li\u1ec7u : H\u1ed9i An \u2013 \u0111\u1ea5t v\u00e0 ng\u01b0\u1eddi<\/p>

17:00<\/strong> Phim truy\u1ec7n : C\u1ed5 t\u00edch chuy\u1ec7n t\u00ecnh - t\u1eadp 28<\/p>

18:00<\/strong> \u0110i\u1ec3m h\u1eb9n x\u1ee9 Tr\u1ea7m H\u01b0\u01a1ng<\/p>

18:20<\/strong> Th\u1ebf gi\u1edbi th\u1ec3 thao<\/p>

18:30<\/strong> Th\u1eddi s\u1ef1 VTV Ph\u00fa Y\u00ean<\/p>

19:00<\/strong> Th\u1eddi s\u1ef1 TH Vi\u1ec7t Nam<\/p>

19:45<\/strong> Caf\u00e9 C\u01b0\u1eddi<\/p>

19:55<\/strong> Phim truy\u1ec7n : \u0110\u1ed9i \u0111\u1eb7c nhi\u1ec7m Hoa M\u1ed9c Lan \u2013 t\u1eadp 17<\/p>

20:45<\/strong> Ph\u00f3ng s\u1ef1 : T\u1ebft h\u01b0\u1edbng v\u1ec1 Tr\u01b0\u1eddng Sa<\/p>

21:00<\/strong> Phim truy\u1ec7n : \u0110\u1ea1i chi\u1ebfn c\u1ed5 kim - t\u1eadp 36<\/p>

21:45<\/strong> Tin t\u1ee9c<\/p>

21:50<\/strong> Phim truy\u1ec7n : Cu\u1ed9c chi\u1ebfn c\u00e1c b\u00e0 v\u1ee3 - t\u1eadp 17<\/p>

22:50<\/strong> Qu\u00e0 t\u1eb7ng cu\u1ed9c s\u1ed1ng<\/p>

23:00<\/strong> Th\u1ebf gi\u1edbi c\u1eadp nh\u1eadt<\/p>

23:20<\/strong> Th\u1ebf gi\u1edbi th\u1ec3 thao<\/p>

23:30<\/strong> T\u00ecnh kh\u00fac v\u01b0\u1ee3t th\u1eddi gian : Mong l\u00e0 gi\u1ea5c m\u01a1<\/p>"
```

When I read the content from my code:

```
String html = "";
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(in));

                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
                in.close();
                html = str.toString();
```

The html display in TextView is still " `Ch\u00e0o bu\u1ed5i s\u00e1ng`"

The result that I expect is "`Chào buổi sáng`". I can't solve this problem.

Another side, if I create a String

```
String test = "Ch\u00e0o bu\u1ed5i s\u00e1ng";
textView.setText(test);
```

then the result will be `Chào buổi sáng`.

I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

```
new InputStreamReader(is, "encoding")
```

Comment: I tried with new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8") but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below .The result  will show you the cause why the code you write not working.

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {

    String test = "Ch\u00e0o bu\u1ed5i s\u00e1ng";

    System.out.println(unicode2String(test));
}
/**
 * unicode 转字符串
 */
public static String unicode2String(String unicode) {

    StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer();

    String[] hex = unicode.split("\\\\u");
    string.append(hex[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < hex.length; i++) {
        // 转换出每一个代码点
        int data = Integer.parseInt(hex[i], 16);

        // 追加成string
        string.append((char) data);
    }

    return string.toString();
}
```

Maybe you code should be as follows:

```
String test = "Ch\u00e0o bu\u1ed5i s\u00e1ng";
textView.setText(unicode2String(test));
```